# Convert the number with php

Tags: php, numbers

What number is this: 8.86E-6

And how can we convert it with PHP?

Is this number equivalent to 0.00000886 or 8.8600000e-6

Comment: Convert it to what?

Comment: it's scientific notiation. just treat `e` as the visual equvalient of `x10^`

Comment: PHP natively understands scientific notation - if you've got a string in that format then any mathematical operations will work fine. If you're looking to convert it for display, look into `sprintf`.